# a For loop to assigned the variables from a list

Tags: r, loops

I have a list named as `storage` which has 30 values.

```
Predictions<- c(storage$predict_AR1_1$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_2$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_3$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_4$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_5$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_6$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_7$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_8$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_9$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_10$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_11$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_12$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_13$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_14$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_15$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_16$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_17$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_18$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_19$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_20$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_21$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_22$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_23$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_24$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_25$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_26$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_27$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_28$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_29$pred[1],
storage$predict_AR1_30$pred[1])
```

I has tried to automate above mentioned process to assign the values of the list as a vector as:

```
for(i in 1:30){
  Predictions <- as.vector(storage$predict_AR1_[i]$pred[1])

}
```

but, it does not work.

Comment: The `[i]` indexing does not work, since the values are not stored in a vector.

Comment: `Predictions <- sapply(storage, function(x) x$pred[1])`